# Anaconda Navigator can not be open

Tags: anaconda3

I installed Anaconda on my Windows 11 computer, but when I run Anaconda Navigator, the Navigator doesn't work. When I started Anaconda Prompt, the error below appeared. I run any command related to conda and the below error appears please help me to fix this error

I hope you can help me fix the above error

Comment: This is my Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'